# How to add a role to user when having basic User model in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Building a lightweight app using basic installation of Yii2.
I need to assign a role for a user but don't want to have users and user roles stored in database.
How can I set a role for users defined in User->users class?

Default User model and default user definition look like this:

```php
class User extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RBAC PhpManager for that that will store all roles info in files instead.

First configure your AuthManager component in `config/web.php`:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

By default it uses 3 files to keep the data:

- `@app/rbac/items.php`
- `@app/rbac/assignments.php`
- `@app/rbac/rules.php`

So make sure there is folder `rbac` in your application's root and that it's write-able by the www process. If you want to place the files somewhere else (or rename them) you can provide the new path in the configuration like:

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
    'itemFile' => // new path here for items,
    'assignmentFile' => // new path here for assignments,
    'ruleFile' => // new path here for rules,
],
```

The rest now is just like in the [Authorization Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization).

1. Prepare roles and permissions ([example in console command](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-console-command) - by running this command once you set all roles; remember that if you want to run it in console you need also configure `console.php` with the same component).
2. Assign role to a user ([example](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#assigning-roles-to-users) - here it's done during the signup but you can do it also in the above command).

Now you can control access with [direct check or behavior configuration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#access-check).

Comment: After some time, I want to say thank you. Sorry for big delay in my response. I was forced to postpone programming of the app. Your message helped me a lot!